# python not recognizing predefined variables

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am fairly new to both python and kivy, and i'm trying to display a list from python as a label in kivy as part of a larger piece of code.

My code is very long, so here are the main bits which concern my query.
.py file:

```
line 0125 class ScreenSeven(Screen):
line 0126     def add_myapp(self,myapp):
line 0127         self.myapp=myapp
.....
line 0204         routine = []
.....
line 2360     ScreenSevenDisplay = StringProperty("here is your workout\n"+" ".join(routine))
line 2361     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
line 2362         super(ScreenSeven, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

.kv file

```
<ScreenSeven>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 40
        spacing: 10
    Label:
        id: ScreenSevenDisplay_label
        text: root.ScreenSevenDisplay
```

All of the code enclosed in lines 0125-2362 are all within the class ScreenSeven. I was hoping my code would display a label in the kivy window containing the string defined in line 2360. However, before I even run the code it says the routine in line 2360 is undefined. I have checked all over for indentation errors and it is clean from them to the best of my knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `routine` is a local variable inside the `add_myapp()` function.  It is not visible outside of that function.

Comment: ...and line 2360 is assigning `ScreenSevenDisplay` as a class variable that isn't tied to any instance of `ScreenSeven`.

Comment: @JohnGordon How would I go about implementing this? I had a look about and inserted a line 203 before 204 which read: global routine. However this did not have the desired effect. It did remove the error symbol next to line 2360 in the editor however the error message name 'routine' is not defined still came out in the console.

Comment: That depends on what `routine` is supposed to be.  Is it something where each `ScreenSeven` instance would want its own copy?  Or is it something that is globally shared among all instances?

Comment: @JohnGordon it would be shared amongst all instances.

Comment: Then you can move it outside of the `add_myapp` function and put it at the class level.